# Looking for scifi book similar to The Day of the Triffids

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens

For years I have been searching  for this science fiction novel that I read in my childhood (somewhere between the 1950s and 1970s). It is similar in concept to [*The Day of the Triffids*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Day_of_the_Triffids). The main character is a fencing enthusiast and is wearing a protective helmet which saves him from being affected by a mysterious radiation which makes humankind fall under the power of a giant alien creature, whose bright eyes are visible in the sky. Our hero gets to the alien ship and there is a free falling through atmosphere inside of an air bubble vessel inside of a block of ice. It was very entertaining but I lost the book and I have unable to remember the title or author.

Answer (score 4):

Certainly never too late to solve one of these - or at least to offer a solution. I believe the OP is querying about *The Flying Eyes* by J. Hunter Holly (1962). Radioactivity, disembodied eyes in the sky, mind control, etc. All in one pulpy book. Also, apparently a football helmet rather than fencing.

Per [Goodreads reviews](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6052112-the-flying-eyes?from_search=true&from_srp=true&qid=vglFNJm7Bh&rank=1):

> "this was some damn entertaining, so-bad-it’s-hilarious cheese! The title pretty much says it all, so if you’re ever in the mood for 150 pages of humans vs. giant flying eyeballs (and the radioactive aliens who sent them out to do their highly evil, highly radioactive bidding), definitely give this a try!"

[image: cover]